# The Grinder - unknown token 'timedTests'

Tags: java, python, jython, grinder

I'm trying to run some simple tests with Grinder. I'm using the JMSReceiver script from the [Script Gallery](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-gallery.html#jmsreceiver.py) and trying to add some statistics, but my Agent throws an exception when it starts up.

A trivial example is:

```
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test

grinder.statistics.registerSummaryExpression("foo","(/ userLong0 timedTests)")
```

Running this throws an exception:

```
...Parse exception: Unknown token 'timedTests', at character 23 of '(/ userLong0 timedTests)'
```

I'm using **grinder-3.11**, **jython-2.5.3**, and I'm running the above Grinder script with:

```
CLASSPATH=lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar:lib/grinder.jar
java -classpath $CLASSPATH net.grinder.Grinder etc/grinder.properties
```

where *grinder.properties* specifies the script to run.

Java version is "1.7.0_03-icedtea", which I think is JDK 7u60 on Centos 6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 5 minutes after posting the question, I found [this wiki page](http://www.cubrid.org/wiki_ngrinder/entry/user-defined-statistic-in-ngrinder). I don't know if it's the version of Grinder that I'm using, but in order to get this to work I have to change

```
grinder.statistics.registerSummaryExpression("foo","(/ userLong0 timedTests)")
```

to

```
grinder.statistics.registerSummaryExpression("foo","(/ userLong0 (count timedTests))")
```

The important difference being the addition of the "count" token. This solves my problem.